# Reload parent page from iframe but append querystring with a new param

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have an iframe that is embeded in a page and when the form on iframe gets submitted I then reload the parent page to fetch updated data on the parent page. To reload the page I use the following code and it reloads the parent page:

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

Now my requirement is to append a new parameter to the existing querystring and then reload it.
For example my current parent page url is `://xyz.com?id=1234`
I would like to reload it as below : `://xyz.com?id=1234&recid=ABC`   I am using this code below but it seems to ignore it completely.

```
$(function () {
$("#InsertButton").click(function () {
   var url = window.top.location.href; 
   console.log('parent url' + url);   
    if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
      url += '&param=1'
    }else{
      url += '?param=1'
    }
   window.top.location.href = url;
   window.top.location.reload(true);
});
});
```